# Find integers $a,b,n$ such that the polynomial $x^2+1$ divide the polynomial $a+bx+x^{n}$

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

I came across with following problem:

Find integers $a,b,n$ such that the polynomial $x^2+1$ divide the polynomial $a+bx+x^{n}$. Or some conditions to verify this property. However, I have no idea to start. We can restrict $a,b$ in the numbers $-1,0,1$. So, we have a set of polynomials of the form: $x^{n}$, $1+x^{n}$,$-1+x+x^{n}$, etc...

Answer (score 2):

If $x^2+1$ divides your polynomial, then $\pm i$ are roots of your polynomial. You can take it from there.